# how to set datamember for bindingsource when using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bindingsource

I am trying to learn EF and databinding with winforms. I have 2 bindingsources. For the first one "bsa" I've set the datasource and did not set the datamember. For the second bindingsource "bsb" I've set the datasource as "bsa" and trying to set datamember property as per below. I am getting an error saying "DataMember property 'Contact.Addresses' cannot be found on the DataSource.".

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
  {
        var contactList = context.Customers.Include("Contact")
            .Include("PrimaryDestination")
            .Include("CustomerType")
            .Include("PrimaryActivity")
            .Include("Reservations").ToList();

        bsa.DataSource = contactList;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bsa;
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        bsb.DataSource = bsa;
```

//Customer has contact navigation property and contact has addresses navigation property

```
        bsb.DataMember = ("Contact.Addresses");        
        dataGridView2.DataSource = bsb;

        dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    }
```

Can I actually set the datamember of the second bindingsource "bsb" without setting the datamember for the first bindingsource "bsa"?

Comment: I'll post this as a comment rather than an answer because I'm not 100% sure but I would expect that you should set the DataMember to simply "Addresses".

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the advise. I tried using "Addresses" didn't work. Customer entity has contact as navigation property and Contact entity has addresses as navigation property. It works if I set the datamember for datasource "bsa" to "Contact"

Comment: Sorry, missed that multi-level relationship.  In that case, you might have to use three BindingSources to make it work automatically, given that you have three entities involved.  At the second level you could use "Contact" as the DataMember and then "Addresses" at the third.  Again, this is intuition only so I'm not sure it would work.  I've never actually tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks again. That has worked. So, does it mean that I need to have a bindingsource for each entity and set the datamember and then chain the bindingsources?

Comment: So it would seem.  As I said, I've never tried this myself so I'm not 100% sure.  I can see why you tried what you did in the first place but, if that didn't work, I would think that a BindingSource per entity must be the way to go, even if the intermediate one isn't actually bound to the UI explicitly.